# Boxing something. drawRect Related

Tags: java

How do I add something like this to my project? 
See this white lines the almost for a box lol Something like that:P

[image]

Comment: @JonSkeet So it is a BorderFactory! Thanks :D

Comment: Yes - I'm coming up with an answer to be more specific. After the edit, the question wasn't too bad - to start with it was way too broad.

Answer (score 2):

The white boxes look like [`TitledBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html), in this case combined with a [`LineBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/LineBorder.html).

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;

class TitledBorderDemo implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TitledBorderDemo());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.white), "Title"));

        panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Label"));

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also see [*How to Use Borders*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/), this is pure not-generated code tutorial, mean that, all code you write, on otherwise you have plugin for eclipse etc. and there is gui, for pull and drop components to your application...